# Send data to php page from button and post results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, http-request

Ok. The problem is I am working on a website that you can easily up-vote or down-vote a certain image/video etc. Now the thing that came up was SENDING the request. I can process most php things and so on so forth, I can also do database requests; but, how do I send a request to my php page? I want it to send from the main page and it will do it without refreshing the page. Also, I tried adding it to a "form", the user clicks the button and it submits, but I need a "id" variable added WITH the request. Now, I know I will need some jquery and Ajax, but I have NO CLUE were to start on that. Here is what I have for my first page:

```
<form action="vote.php">
<input type="image" src="imgs/1.png" name="1" alt="<?php echo $sub; ?>" />
<input type="image" src="imgs/2.png" name="2" alt="NOT" />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id" hidden />
</form>
```

Now, the vote page:

```
<?php

require_once('inc/dbConnect.php');

if (empty($id)) {
  $error = "Which photo to vote?"
}

// Receive vote count, is it UP or DOWN?
// save in variable
// do a check and add it to database, <- I can do this part.  
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using input for image??

Comment: I have no clue. I think I was up too long so I ended up making more mistakes than I intended. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form action="vote.php">
<button type="button" name="vote" value="up">Upvote</button>
<button type="button" name="vote" value="down">Downvote</button>
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="filename_or_unique_id_of_img.jpg">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
form.find('button').on('click',function(){
  var form,url,data;    
      form = $('form');
      url = form.attr('action');
      data = 'voted='+$(this).val()+'&image='+image;

  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    data:data,
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
      alert(data) //'Thanks for voting!'
    }
  })

})
```

PHP:

```
$vote = $_POST['vote'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
//stuff with database
echo 'Thanks for voting!';
```

Comment: Wait... so this will do it without reloading the page?!!?!?!

Comment: Also quick question. I needed the third input to be a php variable. How do I do that?